# the order of several adverbs of time

Tags: adverbs

When I'm given several adverbs of time how do I arrange them? For example, I need to insert these adverbs:

> in the morning / that Thursday / March 22, 2013

into this sentence:

> A tornado had been wreaking havoc.

Comment: Visit this page : http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/adverbs-time/

Comment: On Thursday morning, March 22, 2013 a tornado wrecked havoc.... etc. (Start with smallest) You could say: "On the morning of March 22, 2013"  Why is it being "Thursday" important?

Comment: To paraphrase a well-known communist capitalist - it doesn't matter if a cat has a tail longer than its body, as long as the cat catches the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep Thursday together with March 22,2013 because it's a date. Adding the word "that" before Thursday seems completely unnecessary since you're saying the exact date anyway. "In the morning" can go either before or after the date (although I think theres a slight preference for before). So...

A tornado was wreaking havoc in the morning of Thursday, March 22, 2013.

Also, I think you meant "wreaking havoc".

Comment: Oh I included that because that was the example in our book. I guess this answers my question though, and yeah I did mean wreaking havoc.

Comment: btw, if I'm given a time of day and day of the week, which one should go first? Like for example ..  The party will start at 12 noon on friday? or The party will start on friday at 12 noon.

Comment: The time should come first, since the import of the statement is the time the party starts. But  'Friday at 12 noon'  wouldn't cause any hearer to correct you. If you're asked a general question, such as 'when is the party?' then  'Friday at 12 noon' would be the more common reply.